# calling static method on a new thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

Suppose I have a static method like so:

```
public static string ProcessMessage()
{
     string testString = " this is test ";
     ....
     return testString ;
}
```

and another method SendMessage:

```
public void SendMessage()
{
     Thread th = new Thread(this.ProcessMessage);
     th.Start();
     th.Join();
}
```

What happens when SendMessage is called several times one right after another.

Suppose first thread calls ProcessMessage and is at line 1 and another thread calls ProcessMessage, what happens to the first thread? will it ever finish, since ProcessMessage is a static method? what will ProcessMessage properties look like? will thread 2 overwrite thread 1?

Comment: Um, you appear to be trying to declare a *property* within a method. That's not valid. If you're going to ask us how code behaves at execution time, it needs to be valid code.

Comment: If you tried that you would get `Expected a method with a void signature`

Comment: on top of what Jon said, you can't call `ProcessMessage` through `this`, since it's a static method. You should either use the class name or just the method name, if they're in the same class.

Comment: Have you tried to run your code and and use the tools built inside of Visual Studio determine what in the application's stack?

Comment: sorry, I was copying some sample code. it may be not valid but you get a general idea. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your general question, multiple threads can call a static method, and each thread will process that method call separately.  If static variables are used within the static method, then you may run into cross-threading issues, due to those variables being shared among multiple threads, but the method code itself is simply a set of instructions that will be followed by whatever threads enter it.

In regards to your specific example, the [Thread Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b52fsw6w.aspx) can only be passed either a [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) or a [ThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx) object (and possibly an Int32).  Both types of ThreadStart parameters are delegates with void signatures (they cannot return anything).

Also, since you are calling Thread.Start, followed by [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx).  Thread.Join blocks the calling thread until the waited on thread completes.  Since that is the case, multiple calls to SendMessage() from the same thread will never spawn multiple simultaneous threads.  Instead, each call will create a new thread and then wait for it to finish before moving on to the next call to SendMesage().  This is no better than simply calling ProcessMessage in the original thread.